# Removing SQL Server reporting services from Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I installed SQL server reporting services on one of our front ends and everything stopped working -- images stopped displaying, users got permissions errors.

I tried to remove it from installed programs after I removed the service application and ran

install-sprsservice -uninstall
install-sprserviceproxy -uninstall

The service is still showing up on "Services on Server"  as "starting"

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Please tell me you solved this!